# How to get the unique ID of the website running computer

Tags: php, macos, unique-id

I tried this code for getting the MAC ID , but i get only the host server address, is ther any way to get the unique ID of the computer which the user accessing my website.

```
ob_start(); 
system('ipconfig /all'); 
$mycom=ob_get_contents(); 
ob_clean(); 
$findme = "Physical";
$pmac = strpos($mycom, $findme); 
$mac=substr($mycom,($pmac+36),17); 
echo $mac;
```

Actually i need to know that is it possible to limit access to a particular website based on something specific within a pc other than IP?

Comment: Not unless the client computer sends its MAC address to you.

Comment: this might be possible with the use of a java applet but not on php alone.

Comment: @ jerjer can you please send me some links for that java applet

Answer (score 4):

No. You cannot get the MAC address of someone accessing your website, because your web server does not work with MAC addresses, it works with IPs, and thus it doesn't receive that information.

Comment: Actually i need to know that  is it possible to limit access to a particular website based on something specific within a pc other than IP?

Answer (score 1):

To get this information from the user's computer, you need to run a control or a widget using ActiveX or Java on the user's computer.

Answer (score 0):

Computers do not have unique IDs. You are looking for something that does not exist.